Induced action on vector valued differential forms
Let $F(X)$ be the frame bundle of a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $X$. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ acting by automorphisms on $X$ and let $V$ be a $GL_n(\mathbb C)$-representation.
1)Is
$$\rho(g)(\alpha\otimes X):=L_{g^{-1}}^*(\alpha)\otimes g\cdot X$$
the induced action of $G$ on the algebra of differential forms $\Omega^{\bullet}(X, F(X)\times_{GL_n(\mathbb C)}V)$ with values in the associated bundle $F(X)\times_{GL_n(\mathbb C)}V$?
2)Is it true that for a section $s: X\to F(X)\times_{GL_n(\mathbb C)}V$, we have
$$(F(X)\times_{GL_n(\mathbb C)}V)_{gx}\ni s(gx)=\sum_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}(gx)(e_i)_{gx}=g\cdot(\sum_{\alpha}f_{\alpha}(x)(e_i)_x),$$
where $(e_i)$ is the basis of $V$ and $(e_i)_{gx}:=dg_{x}(e_i)_x$.

maybe don’t use $X$ again in your first equation

It seems like both of these questions are about definitions, which might come down to what specifically you’re reading. In any case, those are how I would define the actions of $G$ on everything involved.
